# Checkerboard Matrix in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

How do I produce a checkerboard matrix in objective c of n number of rows and length? (using the NSLOG to print the Output shown below)

Example:

Input  n = 5

Output is

```
         [1 0 1 0 1
          0 1 0 1 0
          1 0 1 0 1
          0 1 0 1 0 
          1 0 1 0 1]
```

I tried this method below and it gets close. Any help would be appreciated!

```
-(void)checkerboardOne:(int)length {   
    NSMutableArray *squares = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
    for (int y = 1 ; y <= length; y++) { 
        if (y % 2) {
            for (int x = 0 ; x < length; x++) {
                if (x % 2 ) {  
                    [squares addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"]];  
                } else {
                    [squares addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];  
                }
            } //end row 0
        } else {
            for (int x = 0 ; x < length; x++) {
                if (x % 2 ) {
                    [squares addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
                } else {
                    [squares addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"]];
                }
            } //end row 1
        }
        NSLog(@"==========\n%@", squares);
        [squares removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkboard in what form?  `UIImage`?

Comment: Define "it gets close". How close? What do you actually get versus what you actually want?

Comment: BTW - get rid of the needless calls to `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it appears you get output more like:

```
     [0 1 0 1 0
      1 0 1 0 1
      0 1 0 1 0 
      1 0 1 0 1
      0 1 0 1 0]
```

Simply change the outer loop to:

```
for (int y = 0 ; y < length; y++) {
```

to get the desired results.

But there is a much easier way:

```
- (void)checkerboardOne:(int)length {   
    NSMutableArray *squares = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:length * length];

    for (int r = 0; r < length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < length; c++) {
            BOOL isEven = ((r + c) % 2) == 0;
            NSString *result = isEven ? @"1" : @"0";
            [squares addObject:result];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"==========\n%@", squares);
}
```